# Problema con la pagina error 404

Tags: php, html, web, xampp

Alguien sabe a que se debe este error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esa ruta no tengo ningun index el unico que tengo es el index.php y esta en la ruta tutorias/index.php.

Comment: Podrías dar más detalles con respecto al error?, puede ayudar el código html, etc.

Comment: En algun lugar de tu código estas referenciando a index.php con tutorias/php/index.php ... Según lo que dices, deberías ser tutorias/index.php. Sólo corrije eso y se arreglara

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi en mi codigo donde del ajax me manda a esta parte en php tengo esta parte:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$conexion = conexion();

$consulta =$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO T.FAGENDA(NOMBRE_CITA,CLAVE_UNICA, RPE, FECHA_REGISTRO, HORA_REGISTRO, FECHA_CITA, NUMERO_CITA)VALUES(:numeroCitaIndividual,:claveUnicaIndividual,:RPEIndividual,GETDATE(), GETDATE(), :fechaCitaIndividual, :numeroCita);");

$consulta -> bindParam(':numeroCitaIndividual', $numeroCitaIndividual);
$consulta -> bindParam(':claveUnicaIndividual', $claveUnicaIndividual);
$consulta -> bindParam(':RPEIndividual', $RPEIndividual);
$consulta -> bindParam(':fechaCitaIndividual', $fechaCitaIndividual);
$consulta -> bindParam(':numeroCita', $numeroCita);

$numeroCitaIndividual = $_POST['numeroCitaIndividual'];
$claveUnicaIndividual = $_POST['claveUnicaIndividual'];
$RPEIndividual = $_POST['RPEIndividual'];
$fechaCitaIndividual = $_POST['fechaCitaIndividual'];
$numeroCita = $_POST['numeroCita'];

$consulta->execute();

header("Location: index.html");

$conexion=null;
?>
```

Donde

> header("Location: index.html");

es el error simplemente lo quite y se soluciono.